# deactivate/disable OSGI component by name from external bundle

Tags: java, osgi, apache-felix

Is there a way to deactivate a given OSGI component by its name?

There is the `componentContext.disableComponent(componentName)` method - but it only works on components of the same bundle.

What is the best practice solution to do this without adding a new service to the given bundle to deactivate the component?

**Solution:**

When using e.g. Felix this would be :

```
import org.apache.felix.scr.ScrService;

@Reference
private ScrService serviceComponentRuntime;

  public void stopByName(final String componentName)
{
    final org.apache.felix.scr.Component[] components = serviceComponentRuntime.getComponents(componentName);

    for (final org.apache.felix.scr.Component component : components)
    {
        component.disable();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [ServiceComponentRuntime](https://osgi.org/javadoc/r6/cmpn/org/osgi/service/component/runtime/ServiceComponentRuntime.html) service. It allows to introspect and manage any component.

Answer (score 1):

You can enable/disable through the Component Context:

```
@Component(service=ComponentEnabler.class)
public class ComponentEnabler {

  ComponentContext context;

  @Activate
  void activate(ComponentContext context) {
     this.context = context;
  }

  public void enable( String name) {
    this.context.enableComponent(name);
  }
  public void disable( String name) {
    this.context.disableComponent(name);
  }
}
```